# Confusion about the Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

Let $C$ be a category and $F$ a presheaf on $C$. The Yoneda lemma states that the natural transformations $C(-, A)\Rightarrow F$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $F(A)$.

To me, this statement feels unmotivated. I know that if we consider the special case $F=C(-, B)$, then (by the Yoneda lemma) $C(-, -)$ yields an embedding (that is, a full and faithful functor) of $C$ into the category of presheaves on $C$. This feels quite motivated, since embedding $C$ into the category of presheaves on $C$ feels a bit like embedding a field $k$ into its algebraic closure $\bar{k}$. Furthermore, the category of presheaves also feels more concrete than the abstract category $C$.

But why is one interested in the general statement where $F$ can be any presheaf whatsoever. Why is this a natural statement? How does one get the idea to consider the Yoneda lemma as stated above?

I have yet another question about the Yoneda lemma. As I said, one has an embedding of $C$ into $[C^\text{op}, \mathbf{Sets}]$ (the category of presheaves on $C$). By considering covariant functors $C\to\mathbf{Sets}$ instead of presheaves, one can also prove a covariant version of the Yoneda lemma, which states that the natural transformations $C(A, -)\Rightarrow F$ (for $F\colon C\to \mathbf{Sets}$ any functor) are in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $F(A)$. From this one gets an embedding of $C$ into $[C, \mathbf{Sets}]^\text{op}$.

So to sum up, one can embed $C$ into both $[C^\text{op}, \mathbf{Sets}]$ *and* $[C, \mathbf{Sets}]^\text{op}$. Question: How do $[C^\text{op}, \mathbf{Sets}]$ and $[C, \mathbf{Sets}]^\text{op}$ relate to each other?

What I find a bit weird about the situation: At first, I expected $[C^\text{op}, \mathbf{Sets}]$ and $[C, \mathbf{Sets}]^\text{op}$ to be equivalent. But a general fact is that
$$[C, D]^\text{op}\cong [C^\text{op}, D^\text{op}],$$
thus
$$[C, \mathbf{Sets}]^\text{op}\cong[C^\text{op}, \mathbf{Sets}^\text{op}],$$
which is not $[C^\text{op}, \mathbf{Sets}]$.

Comment: An interesting view is https://mathoverflow.net/a/15143, which goes via "a category is basically a template of a many-sorted algebraic theory with unary functions". An object is a type, an arrow is a function, and a functor into Set is a concrete realisation of the theory. Yoneda is a natural statement about homomorphisms from the "term models" of the theory: it says "the term models at object $A$ are in bijection with the elements of $A$ when you concretely realised the theory", which is fair enough since the realisation of the term model is fixed by the element of $A$ the term got sent to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible answer to this question.

Let's take the viewpoint that functors are representations of categories.

**First, why is this sensible?**

Well, recall that categories are generalizations of monoids (and consequently groups as well), since a one object category is the same thing as a monoid.
If $M$ is a monoid, then we can define a category, $C$, with one object, $*$, hom set $C(*,*)=M$, and unit and composition given by the unit and multiplication in $M$. Conversely, given a one object category $C$, $C(*,*)$ is a monoid with composition as multiplication, and these constructions are inverse to each other.

From now on, if $M$ is a monoid, or $G$ is a group, I'll write $BM$ or $BG$ for the corresponding one object category.

Now, what about functors? Well, what are functors $[BG,k\newcommand\Vect{\text{-}\mathbf{Vect}}\Vect]$?

Well, we need to pick a vector space $V$ to send $*$ to, and we need to pick a monoid homomorphism $G\to \newcommand\End{\operatorname{End}}\End V$. Since $G$ is a group, this is equivalent to a group homomorphism $G\to \operatorname{GL}(V)$. In other words, functors from $BG$ to $k\Vect$ are exactly the same as linear group representations, and you can check that natural transformations of functors correspond exactly to the $G$-equivariant linear maps.

Similarly, when we replace $k\Vect$ with $\newcommand\Ab{\mathbf{Ab}}\Ab$, or $\newcommand\Set{\mathbf{Set}}\Set$, we get $G$-modules and $G$-sets respectively.

Specifically, these are all *left* $G$-actions, since a functor $F:BG\to \Set$ must preserve composition, so
$F(gh)=F(g)F(h)$, and we define $g\cdot x$ by $F(g)(x)$. Thus $(gh)\cdot x = g\cdot (h\cdot x))$.

A contravariant functor $\newcommand\op{\text{op}}BG^\op\to \Set$ gives a right $G$-action, since now
$F(gh)=F(h)F(g)$, so if we define $x\cdot g = F(g)(x)$, then we have
$$x\cdot (gh) =F(gh)(x) = F(h)F(g)x = F(h)(x\cdot g) = (x\cdot g)\cdot h.$$

Thus we should think of covariant functors $[C,\Set]$ as left $C$-actions in $\Set$,
and we should think of contravariant functors $[C^\op,\Set]$ as right $C$-actions in $\Set$.

**Yoneda Lemma in Context**

Representable presheaves now correspond to free objects in a single variable in the following sense.

The Yoneda lemma is that we have a natural isomorphism
$$
[C^\op,\Set](C(-,A),F)\simeq F(A)\simeq \Set(*,F(A)).
$$

In other words, $C(-,A)$ looks a lot like the left adjoint to the "forgetful" functor that sends a presheaf $F$ to its evaluation at $A$, $F(A)$, but evaluated on the singleton set $*$.

In fact, we can turn $C(-,A)$ into a full left adjoint by noting that
$$\Set(S,F(A)) \simeq \prod_{s\in S} F(A) \simeq \prod_{s\in S}[C^\op,\Set](C(-,A),F)
\simeq [C^\op,\Set](\coprod_{s\in S} C(-,A), F),$$
and $\coprod_{s\in S} C(-,A)\simeq S\times C(-,A)$.

Thus one way of stating the Yoneda lemma is that $S\mapsto S\times C(-,A)$ is left adjoint to the evaluation at $A$ functor (in the sense that the two statements are equivalent via a short proof). Incidentally, there is also a right adjoint to the evaluation at $A$ functor, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2187889/90543) for the argument.

**Relating this back to more familiar notions**

First thing to notice in this viewpoint is that we now have notions of "free on an object" rather than just "free." I.e., I tend to think of $C(-,A)$ as being the free presheaf in one variable on $A$ (this is not standard terminology, just how I think of it).

Now we should be careful, a free object isn't just an object, it's an object *and a basis*. In this case, our basis (element that freely generates the presheaf) is the identity element $1_A$.

Thinking about it this way, the proof of the Yoneda lemma should hopefully be more intuitive. After all, the proof of the Yoneda lemma is the following:

$C(-,A)$ is generated by $1_A$, since $f^*1_A=f$, for any $f\in C(B,A)$, so natural transformations $C(-,A)$ to $F$ are uniquely determined by where they send $1_A$. (Analogous to saying $1_A$ spans $C(-,A)$). Moreover, any choice $\alpha\in F(A)$ of where to send $1_A$ is valid, since we can define a natural transformation by "extending linearly" $f=f^*1_A \mapsto f^*\alpha$ (this is analogous to saying $1_A$ is linearly independent, or forms a basis).

The covariant version of the Yoneda lemma is the exact same idea, except that we are now working with left representations of our category.

**Examples of the Yoneda lemma in more familiar contexts**

Consider the one object category $BG$, then the Yoneda lemma says that
the right regular representation of $G$ is the free right $G$-set in one variable (with the basis element being the identity, $1_G$).
(The free one in $n$-variables is the disjoint union of $n$ copies of the right regular representation.)

The embedding statement is now that $G$ can be embedded into $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ via $g\mapsto -\cdot g$.

This also works in enriched contexts. A ring is precisely a one object category enriched in abelian groups, and the Yoneda lemma in this context says that the right action of $R$ on itself (often denoted $R_R$) is the free right $R$-module in one variable, with the basis being the unit element $1_R$.
(The free one in $n$-variables is now the direct sum of $n$ copies of $R_R$)

The embedding statement here is that $R$ can be embedded into the endomorphism ring of its underlying abelian group via $r\mapsto (-\cdot r)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is your perspective somehow related to the one mentioned by Patrick Stevens?

Comment: @user762130 I think they are roughly the same idea, but from two different perspectives. I'm answering from an algebraist's perspective, whereas that answer seems to be coming at it from a logician's perspective. I'm not a logician myself, so perhaps that's not quite right. In particular, I don't quite understand what a term model is, but it seems to be the same idea as a "free object" in my sense, so yes they should be related.